# Frameworks using Smarty

Tags: php, frameworks, smarty

Is there any PHP framework that uses Smarty as template engine?

Comment: I swear to [whatever PHP deity] that Smarty doesn't do anything to reduce development time.

Comment: Very few frameworks use Smarty out of the box (I'm not aware of any that do), but most can be integrated with it. That said, there's a good reason that most frameworks don't use Smarty…

Comment: I find it easier to implement, easier use, faster to develop and more reliable to use PHP (without any frameworks like smarty) for generating output. Files that generate HTML reside in their own directory structure (e.g., `html/<module>/<action>`, though in my case every module may use it's own structure with some basic guidelines), and these files do nothing more than just outputting HTML and values of previously defined variables. Fast, easy to use, no technical restrictions.

Comment: @will : can you please name those frameworks? thnx.

Comment: benTahir: Any major framework with good extensibility features can have Smarty integrated into it. For example, Zend, Kohana, CakePHP, CodeIgniter, etc. Just Google it and you'll find guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thinphp framework uses Smarty as template, also zoop framework, MODx not entirely a framework but also uses Smarty. Rain framework uses something very similar to smarty.

Comment: thinphp framework , yes it does the job. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can: [Integrating Smarty with the Zend Framework](http://devzone.zend.com/article/120)

Comment: 404 - This is not the URL you were looking for :-(

Comment: @r-benTahir: I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

MvcSkel framework has Smarty integration: https://github.com/ysubach/mvcskel#readme
If any questions, ask me - I am one of MvcSkel authors.

Answer (score 1):

You can find Smarty in several CMS systems (CMSMadeSimple is one that comes to mind, and XOOPS), but not much out there in plain MVC frameworks. That goes for any template engine. That makes sense... you can bolt any template engine onto any of them, so why force the developer to choose a template engine, or maybe they just want PHP?

Also, Smarty has been somewhat idle in development up until the recent version 3 release, so who knows what will be cropping up. Template inheritance was a nice addition.

Comment: well Smarty has great future in the web development . PHP is so blessed with it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that smarty is used as a template engine in any of modern php frameworks mainly because it was developed and matured **before** most of them.

There are many ways to integrate it with many of the popular ones though.

Comment: ok Finally i have found a framework that [Rain framework](http://www.rainframework.com/).. so simple and has its own template engine (raintpl) for the view although it also supports the traditional way. hope it helps so many new comers like me. thanx ya all for the help.. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

[Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/) supports several template engines one of them being Smarty through the [SmartyBundle](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Phraw micro framework uses Smarty as suggested template engine: [phraw.dav-muz.net](http://phraw.dav-muz.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is over a year old but client requirements forced me to write a Smarty plugin for [Lithium](http://www.lithify.me) PHP.

It's not "out of the box" but it is tightly integrated with the frameworks core features. https://github.com/joseym/li3_smarty